# Как получить значение атребута XML тега в чистом виде при парсинге файла

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser

Файл содержит оферы вот в таком формате

```html
<offers>
  <offer id="175" name="Платье отрезное по талии П-330/2">
    <name>Платье отрезное по талии П-330/2</name>
    <price>1320</price>
    <currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
    <categoryId>127</categoryId>
    <categoryId>15</categoryId>
    <categoryId>134</categoryId>
    <categoryId>124</categoryId>
    <categoryId>26</categoryId>
    <categoryId>125</categoryId>
    <typePrefix>Платье отрезное по талии</typePrefix>
    <vendor>Modellos.ru</vendor>
    <model>PlateP-330246-model-46-size</model>
    <description>Удобный наряд, из мягкого плотного трикотажа. Модель отрезная по линии талии с расклешённой юбкой. Горловина оформлена V-образным вырезом. Втачные рукава длиной ¾. Платье без застежкиСиний шарфик в подарок. </description>
    <country_of_origin>Россия</country_of_origin>
    <param name="Цвет">синий +серый</param>
    <param name="Состав">трикотаж - ПЭ 60%, вискоза 35%, лайкра 5%</param>
    <param name="Длина изделия по спинке">46 размер - 97см., 48 размер - 99см., 50 размер - 99см., 52 размер - 100см., 54 размер - 101см., 56 размер - 102см.</param>
    <param name="Размер фотомодели">54</param>
    <param name="Рост фотомодели">162</param>
    <param name="размер" unit="RU">46</param>
    <vendorCode>П-330/2</vendorCode>
  </offer>
  <offer id="204" name="Платье П-337">
    <name>Платье П-337</name>
    <price>1390</price>
    <currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
    <categoryId>127</categoryId>
    <categoryId>15</categoryId>
    <categoryId>134</categoryId>
    <categoryId>124</categoryId>
    <categoryId>26</categoryId>
    <categoryId>125</categoryId>
    <typePrefix>Платье</typePrefix>
    <vendor>Modellos.ru</vendor>
    <model>PlateP-33744-model-44-size</model>
    <description>Модель прилегающего силуэта из плотного трикотажа, декорирована погонами на плечах и металлическими молниями на уровне бедер. Рукава втачные длиной ¾. Платье без застежки</description>
    <country_of_origin>Россия</country_of_origin>
    <param name="Цвет">серый</param>
    <param name="Состав">трикотаж - ПЭ 60%, вискоза 35%, лайкра 5%</param>
    <param name="Длина изделия по спинке">44 размер - 97см., 46 размер - 98см., 48 размер - 99см., 50 размер - 100см., 52 размер - 101см., 54 размер - 102см.</param>
    <param name="Размер фотомодели">44</param>
    <param name="Рост фотомодели">172</param>
    <param name="размер" unit="RU">44</param>
    <vendorCode>П-337</vendorCode>
  </offer>
</offers>
```

мне нужно получить значение атребута `id` тега `offer` и записать его в массив

написал следующую функцию

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('offers.xml');
$past_offers = array();

foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer){
    if (!in_array($offer->attributes()->id, $past_offers)) {
        array_push($past_offers, $offer->attributes()->id);
    }
}
print_r($past_offers);
```

После выполнение получаю массив такого вида

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 175
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 204
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 226
        )
)
```

А хотелось бы получить массив который будет иметь только значения.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 175 
    [1] => 204
    [2] => 226
)
```

иначе мое условие `if (!in_array($offer->attributes()->id, $each_offers)) {`
просто не работает. И в массив попадают повторяющиеся оферы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('offers.xml');
$past_offers = array();

foreach($xml->>offers->offer as $offer){
    if (!in_array($offer->attributes()->id, $past_offers)) {
        array_push($past_offers, (int) $offer->attributes()->id);
    }
}
print_r($past_offers);
```

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов исправил ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<offers>
  <offer id="175" name="Платье отрезное по талии П-330/2">
    <name>Платье отрезное по талии П-330/2</name>
  </offer>
  <offer id="204" name="Платье П-337">
    <name>Платье П-337</name>
  </offer>
</offers>');

$past_offers = array();

foreach ($xml->offer as $offer){
    if (!in_array($offer->attributes()->id, $past_offers)) {
        array_push($past_offers, (int) $offer->attributes()->id);
//                               ^^^^^
    }
}

print_r($past_offers);
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 175
    [1] => 204
)
```

Трюк в приведении `SimpleXMLElement` к желаемому типу.

Также можно использовать такой приём:

```
array_push($past_offers, current($offer->attributes()->id));
```

Хотя тут менее очевидно что делается, потому лучше как выше.

Comment: а можно как то с помощью xpath достучаться до значения атрибута или xpath на про это?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов это вам другой вопрос надо задать, здесь ответ принимайте пожалуйста

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов благодарю